# htaccess redirect a specific extension to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, cdn

I wish to redirect/rewrite a specific extension (mp3) in a specific folder to a subdomain which uses a CDN.

To make things more clear I want just the mp3 extension in folder 'compositions' to a subdomain only when someone tries to download the mp3 like

```
http://www.example.com/compositions/interception.mp3
```

to

```
http://sub.example.com/interception.mp3 (subdomain on push zone CDN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `RewriteCond` to match the hostname `www.example.com`, when matched perform the rewrite of mp3's in the `compositions/` directory.

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the domain matches www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]

# Rewrite mp3's from composition/ to the CDN, capture filename in $1
# Performs a 301 redirect
RewriteRule ^compositions/(.*)\.mp3$ http://sub.example.com/$1.mp3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't working! :( Can you please try it at your end?

Comment: I can't try it out because I don't know what your domain is.

Comment: I tried and it keeps redirecting in a loop to /compositions and then to compositions/compositions then compositions/compositions/compositions and so on..

Comment: @user1170540 Do you have other rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: Yes. I'm currently trying to use the htaccess in folder without any other rules..

Comment: Post all your rules above. The rule I have here _can't_ cause a rewrite loop alone, because it redirects off to another domain.

Comment: Plug it into http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and test the URL `http://www.example.com/compositions/interception.mp3`  It will correctly show a redirection to `http://sub.example.com/interception.mp3`  If you have other rules interfering, you need to get them squared away.

Comment: Put these rules before all your other rules, right beneath your `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: @user1170540 Then you need to debug it by commenting out different rules while leaving the new one in until you find the one that causes the loop.

Comment: I commented ALL other rules together and this still goes in a loop. This is the root htaccess and all associated folders do not have any other htaccess. Any suggestions?